# Modify HTML and open in new window

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to modify the contents of an HTML template and open it in a new window:

```
          var center_left = (screen.width / 2) - (1100 / 2);
          var center_top = (screen.height / 2) - (600 / 2);
          newWindow = window.open('','mywindow','width=1100,height=600,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,left=' + center_left + ',top=' + center_top);
          var adminDoc = adminWindow.document.body;
          domConst.place('adminReportTemplate.html', adminDoc);
```

this code opens a new window with the template but how do I access the DOM to manipulate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **window opener** property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   <button onclick="openWindow()">Open Window</button>

   <script>
    function openWindow() {
        var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "width=400, height=200");
        newWindow.document.write("<p>This is a new window'</p>");
        newWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>");
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

For further information take a look at the originator of this example: [Window Opener www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure this property will allow me to manipulate the Dom of the Html template I am opening to a new window. In other words, I have a HTML template file that i would like to open in the new window and manipulate the DOM by element ID or some other means.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution-

Using 'dojo/text' I converted my Html Template into a string, then wrote that string to the new window using newWindow.document.write(htmlTemplateString)

I was then able to getElementbyID and modify the contents of the new window. Not sure if this is the best way but it seems to work ok.